# UITabBar reload UIView on touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to call a method when a tab bar icon is touched, even if its already the selected icon? I want to make it remove a sub view when touched if the subview is showing.

I'm sure there must be a way to do this because I see it in other apps, but I cannot find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Apple Documentation for UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) :

> `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item`
>
> Sent to the delegate when the user selects a tab bar item. (required)

- As you noticed I think, and as stated by Apple docs, this message is sent *only when a tab is selected*
- An important note, there is already a *(not-documented?)* default `UIKit` behavior of tapping a selected tab bar button :

  > If the tab contains a `UINavigationViewController` **it will send to it a  `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`** message. You can check this on any **iOS application**.

**So beware before overriding this default (and user expected) behavior, which is, *generally*, a bad idea.**
Apple has probably hidden what you want to do in its `UIKit` API, *on purpose*.

But if you want anyway does this, here are some ideas:

- **Small, but not easy hack**: Once the tabBar has been displayed, recursively browse its `.subviews` tree to find (I expect, to be confirmed) `UIButton`s inherited classes (=private `UITabBarButtons` or something like) to add your target/selector pairs on TouchUp event *(you might have to remove default behavior first, which might be tricky)*
- **Worst solution, but might be the only one**: Do not use `UITabBar`, but a custom class. I'm pretty sure there are ready-to-use open source components that mimics `UITabBar`, but sorry, I never used/searched one.

Comment: then that brings me to a second question, if you don't mind, is it possible to use the functionality of a UINavigationController with out the bars at the top?

Comment: I guess you can by tricking with something *(dirty)* like `.origin.y -= 44` and `.frame.heigth += 44` or maybe just hiding `navigationBar`. Dirty.... you really should consider adding a refresh button, more explicit to user, instead of using "tricks" to refresh a view, which is bad from a UX point of view. (Users will never figure how to refresh view!)

Comment: my app is very demanding of screen real estate you are probably right though, I will try what you suggested but i will probably have to change up anyways. thank you.

Comment: Except for young geeks, "tricky" UI like the twitter pull-to-refresh (that btw, could be a solution in your case) **are a bad idea**

Answer (score 0):

You can have delegates for the UITabbarcontroller,

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Also please go through this document: [UITabBarController delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)